# Gradle - Apply configuration to all projects using plugin

Tags: java, android, gradle

In a multi-project Gradle build, how can I apply one bit of config to all projects that use a certain plug-in?

I want to see a bit more output from my java-based projects when tests are being run. I've found this snippet, which does what I want:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

Copy and pasting this into the five out of six projects that use Java (one uses the Android plugin) seems inelegant. How can I put this in once, but have Gradle not try and apply it to the non-Java project?

Comment: you can use ` project.plugins.withType(GroovyBasePlugin) {}` hook to lazy apply logic when a plugin is applied. (in this case GroovyBasePlugin)

Answer (score 1):

See the [organising build logic](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html) section in the gradle documentation for various options for code re-use.

I'd probably use a `subprojects` closure in the root `build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
    test {
        testLogging {
            events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        }
    }
}
```